# Interpolation with $p$-adic formal power series in $\mathbb Z_p[[x]]$

Tags: number-theory, power-series, p-adic-number-theory

It's a classical exercise in complex analysis that one could find a holomorphic function with given values on a set of points on the complex plane without limit points.

What about the p-adic analogue? For example given $a_n \in \Bbb N$ for any positive integer $n$, when could we find $f \in \mathbb Z_p[[x]]$ such that $f((1+p)^n-1)=a_n$ for all $n$?

Comment: Are you saying that $\{a_n\}$ is to be an infinite sequence of integers?

Comment: @Lubin Yes, I want to know when we can find $f$ with given values $a_n$ at the point $x_n=(1+p)^n-1$.  I know the theory of Coleman power series says that every norm compatible system is interpolated by a power series at the points $\zeta_{p^n} -1$, but here I want to consider more general points.

Comment: I’ve been giving this some thought, but mostly spinning my creaky wheels. The numbers $(1+p)^n-1$ are all in $p\Bbb Z_p$, and so have limit points, while the numbers $\zeta_{p^n}$ do not. So your question, as stated, poses rather different problems, compared to Coleman’s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your choice of the set $\{(1+p)^n-1\}$ on which you want $f$ to take the values $a_n$ is not so good.

Except when $p=2$, the logarithm, defined on the multiplicative group $1+p\Bbb Z_p$ by the usual formula $\log(1+x)=-\sum_1^\infty(-x)^m/m$, and the exponential $\exp(x)=\sum_0^\infty x^m/m!\,$, are convergent on the closed subdisk $p\Bbb Z_p$ and are inverse to each other. Once you make the associate analytic change of coordinatization, therefore, you’re really asking to find an analytic $F$ such that for every $n\ge0$, you get $F(np)=a_n$. You’re really asking whether $pn\mapsto a_n$ is a $p$-adically analytic function of $n$. (The $2$-adic situation, where you’re asking about powers of $3$, is different only in detail.)

As I said in my comment, the roots of unity are wide-spaced in the $p$-adic universe, unlike the complex universe, where they’re dense in a subset that’s locally $\Bbb R$; the reverse is true of the natural integers, or your numbers $(1+p)^n-1$, which are wide-spaced in the complex universe, but dense in a subset that’s locally $\Bbb Q_p$.